# Need to clear the session value, session value not carried into another page

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a problem in carrying session values between the pages.

I was struggling for 3 days for this issue.

Help me to overcome from this issue.

`index.php` (login page):

```
// initially declaring a variable with null value

!! include "conn.php";
   @session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
   {
    $_SESSION['uname'] = " ";
   }
   else
   {
    $_SESSION['uname'] = " ";
   }
?>
//later assigning the value
$usrname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
    $chk = mysqli_query($con,"select * from members WHERE username='$usrname'");
    while($value = mysqli_fetch_array($chk))
    {
        $realpassword = $value['password'];
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
    }
    if(!isset($realpassword))
    {
        $realpassword  = "";
    }
    if($realpassword == $pass)
    {
         echo "<script>window.location.assign('dashboard.php');</script>";
    }
```

`Dashboard.php` (Dashboard):

```
// In dashboard

@session_start();
include "conn.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])&&$_SESSION['uname']!="")
{
$uname =$_SESSION['uname'];
}
else{
 echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://www.website.com');</script>";
}

/// This page working fine
```

In page 3:

```
/// Session value not carried into this page .. when this page loads automatically logouts and redirect into home page

session_start();
include "conn.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])&&$_SESSION['uname']=="")
{
  echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://www.website.com');</script>";
}
$uname =$_SESSION['uname'];
```

Comment: is your session variable still set before redirecting with :

echo "window.location.assign('dashboard.php');" ?

Comment: use session_start() before any conent is sent! *@session_start();* is no good practice

Comment: `@` is not good practice, period. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you"

Comment: You should do the redirect with `header` call. Withouth JS the redirect won't work.

Comment: This code is **very** vulnerable for multiple attacks :/ And why are you using: `if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
{
$_SESSION['uname'] = " ";
}
else
{
 $_SESSION['uname'] = " ";
}`. This is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']) && $_SESSION['uname'] == "")
 {
 echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://www.website.com');</script>";
 }
```

Should be (OR not AND) :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']) OR $_SESSION['uname']==""){
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://www.website.com');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as pseudo code

**index.php:**

```
1 start a session
2 if uname is set in session, set it to one space
3 otherwise, set it to one space

4 get data from db
5 if we have data, set uname in session to POST data uname
```

**in "page 3":**

```
1 if uname is NOT set in session OR uname in session is empty string
2     logoff
3 otherwise 
4     proceed ...
```

according to the other answer and 2) - 3) in index, Condition in 1) in "page 3" is never true. And in dashboard, you may see similar problems resulting from "deleting" the `$_SESSION['uname']` with one space `" "` and checking for empty string `""`

Change index.php:

```
include "conn.php";
@session_start();

unset($_SESSION['uname']); // delete previous values unconditionally (!)
```